# How to define mailto link in HTML, where body variable is in HTML format?

Tags: html, mailto

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:email@mail.com?subject=New&body=<b>bold text</b>">Send Email</a>
```

I need "bold text" to be really bold, not surround with tags.

Comment: ((( parser(( Anywhere I need to user html tags in mailto body

Answer (score 2):

> How to define mailto link in HTML, where body variable is in HTML format?

As far as I know, this isn't possible at all. The `mailto:` syntax is limited to text-only content.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you *can* specify a body, although only a limited amount of email clients do this.

So for web, probably best to not use. But if you do use it, remember to URL encode your body, as you'll get validation errors in the least.